# React: Can I find out what elements have been updated in an array state?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

If I have a React array state created with the `useState` hook, is it possible to somehow find out what elements have been updated? My intention is to run some code whenever the state updates, inside of a `useEffect` hook, but I would like to have access to the index(es) of the updated array elements. Is this possible?

Comment: Could you add the code?

Comment: Surely you've updated the state yourself, so you already have that information available.

Comment: @RobertoZvjerković I would like to run this code in a `useEffect` hook, after the state has updated. Apologies for not mentioning that.

Comment: I get that, but why would you need the hook for that anyway? Where did the update even happen? It seems natural to "run some code" when the update happens and you have all the information there, instead of doing it on the next render cycle?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can but if the indexes are not changed.

You can hold your previous state and in your useEffect, iterate through your new array and check if the element at index i is equal to the corresponding element in previous state or not:

```js
const [myArray, setMyArray] = useState([]);
const [myPreviousArray, setMyPreviousArray] = useState([]);

// Assume we have a function that updates the state
const handleArrayDataChange = (newValue) => {
  setMyPreviousArray([...myArray]);
  setMyArray(newValue);
}

useEffect(() => {
  myArray.forEach((item, index) => {
   if(JSON.stringify(item) !== JSON.stringify(myPreviousArray[index])) {
    // The item is updated
   }
  });
}, [myArray]);
```

Answer (score -3):

> My intention is to run some code whenever the state updates, inside of a useEffect hook,

This can be done by passing downn the state in the dependecy array of useEffect.

```
const [nameArray, setNameArray] = useState([]);

useEffect(() => {
// things you want to do
},[nameArray]);
```